# Split one table row into multiples of 5s column

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, modulo, divide

Say I have an array with 11 elements

```
var sizeArr = ['abc','bcd','cde','def','efg','fgh','ghi','hij'.'ijk','klm','lmn'];
```

I wanted to create an HTML table based on the array above but wanted to divide the row into 5 columns. I have some code that looks similar to this:

```
var cntr = 1;
for (....) {
    if (cntr == 1 || cntr % 6 == 0) {
        html += "<tr>";
    }

     html +="<td>.....</td>";

    if (cntr == sizeArr.length|| cntr % 5 == 0) {
        html += "</tr>";
    }
}
```

This code works ok for the first 10 elements. The output will be similar to his:

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <p class='COLUMN-DATA-PADDING-TXT'>10 D(M) US</p>
      <p class='COLUMN-DATA-PADDING-TXT'>12</p>
   </td>
   <td>
      <p class='COLUMN-DATA-PADDING-TXT'>10.5 D(M) US</p>
      <p class='COLUMN-DATA-PADDING-TXT'>6</p>
   </td>
   <td>
      <p class='COLUMN-DATA-PADDING-TXT'>11 D(M) US</p>
      <p class='COLUMN-DATA-PADDING-TXT'>6</p>
   </td>
   <td>
      <p class='COLUMN-DATA-PADDING-TXT'>11.5 D(M) US</p>
      <p class='COLUMN-DATA-PADDING-TXT'>12</p>
   </td>
   <td>
      <p class='COLUMN-DATA-PADDING-TXT'>12 D(M) US</p>
      <p class='COLUMN-DATA-PADDING-TXT'>4</p>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
      <p class='COLUMN-DATA-PADDING-TXT'>13 D(M) US</p>
      <p class='COLUMN-DATA-PADDING-TXT'>4</p>
   </td>
   <td>
      <p class='COLUMN-DATA-PADDING-TXT'>14 D(M) US</p>
      <p class='COLUMN-DATA-PADDING-TXT'>6</p>
   </td>
   <td>
      <p class='COLUMN-DATA-PADDING-TXT'>8 D(M) US</p>
      <p class='COLUMN-DATA-PADDING-TXT'>8</p>
   </td>
   <td>
      <p class='COLUMN-DATA-PADDING-TXT'>8.5 D(M) US</p>
      <p class='COLUMN-DATA-PADDING-TXT'>8</p>
   </td>
   <td>
      <p class='COLUMN-DATA-PADDING-TXT'>9 D(M) US</p>
      <p class='COLUMN-DATA-PADDING-TXT'>6</p>
   </td>
</tr>
<td>
   <p class='COLUMN-DATA-PADDING-TXT'>9.5 D(M) US</p>
   <p class='COLUMN-DATA-PADDING-TXT'>6</p>
</td>
```

Notice the last td doesn't have the enclosing tr on it.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that others can help you? With what you currently have, it is not complete or verifiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show what condition you are using in your `for` loop, so it's not really possible to be sure what is going wrong with *your* code. I would guess that it's not a good sign that the second `if` condition is testing `cntr == sizeArr.length`, because if the loop counter is equal to the array's `.length` that means that the "current" element at `sizeArr[cntr]` is `undefined` - the last element in the array is at position `length-1`.

Anyway, as far as implementing your requirement, what I'd suggest is making it a bit simpler by adding the first `<tr>` and final `</tr>` tags *outside* the loop, because then you only need one `if` statement:

```js
var sizeArr = ['abc','bcd','cde','def','efg','fgh','ghi','hij','ijk','klm','lmn'];

var html = "";
var cols = 5;
for (var i = 0; i < sizeArr.length; i++) {
  if (i % cols === 0 && i > 0) {
    html += "</tr><tr>";
  }
  html += "<td>" + sizeArr[i] + "</td>";
}
html = "<tr>" + html + "</tr>";
// do something with the html, e.g., for demo purposes:
console.log(html);
document.body.innerHTML = "<table>" + html + "</table>";
```

Comment: Thank you! this has helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do the job with `Array.prototype.reduce()`. You may chose not to use the arrow functions but the idea is here. You can check the results on the console to see the tags though.

```js
var sizeArr = ['abc','bcd','cde','def','efg','fgh','ghi','hij','ijk','klm','lmn'],
    myTable = sizeArr.reduce((p,c,i,a) => { i%5 === 0 && (p+="<tr>");
                                            i%5 === 4 || i === a.length-1 ? p+= "<td>" + c + "</td></tr>"
                                                                          : p+= "<td>" + c + "</td>"
                                            return p},"");
    
document.write("<table>"+myTable+"</table>");
console.log(myTable);
```